# ruby on rails: Uploading image in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am doing a project which allows user to upload image.
My  problem is how can i save the information of image in database MySQL like:
image_path;
image_type;
image_desc:

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem called [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) available. [Use it](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails.html).

Comment: Thanks... i already use the Paperclip for uploading now what i want is to save the image information in MySQL database

Comment: If you go through the README, it is described that you should add certain fields to you model and say has_attached_file :whatever and so on. Please go through the documentation. It's pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gem https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip. The image_desc you can to save independently.

```
Image.create(:image => params[:file], :image_desc => params[:desc])
```

Comment: hey! my images are saved in hard disk but i want to save the information regarding that image in database MySQL

Comment: I think the image_path you know Rails.root.to_s + "your/path/to/file". File type as paperclip https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/upfile.rb#8

Comment: Not getting your point clearly,like as i save the image in hard disk ,i want its save the information of that image in MySQL like name ,path,type ....